# Django how to write custom authenication that works for anonymos user?

Tags: django, authentication, permissions

I have a problem, becouse I have my django app, and whole logic related to permissions is combined in my custom permissions class - something like this:

```
class MyPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        endpoint = get_object_or_404(DataSetApiEndpoint, pk=view.kwargs["pk"])

        user_is_author = False
        can_read = False
        can_write = False

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            is_author = endpoint.author == request.user
            can_read = ...
            can_write = ...

        user_can_read = (
            is_author
            or can_read
            or endpoint.is_public
        )
        user_can_write = is_author or can_write

        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            if user_can_read:
                return True
        elif user_can_write:
            return True
        return False
```

As you can see, if endpoint is public, even anonymous user can read from it. It works on localhost, but when I deployed it to server and tried to access public endpoint without logging in, I got:

> "detail": "Invalid username/password."

If I was logged in, everything worked fine. As I found out, this message comes from rest BasicAuthentication. My question is, if I have permission class that takes care of whole permissions staff, is simple authentication without any checking enought? And do you have some example of authentication class tahtg would work for unathorized user when endpoint is public (all I've found worked only for logged in user)?

edit:
View looks like this:

```
class DataView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = DataSerializer
    accessed_obj_pk = "pk"
    throttle_classes = [EndpointRateThrottle]
    permission_classes = [MyPermissions]
        
    def get_queryset(self):
        # django query with some filters
        ...

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        for data_row in queryset:
            data_row.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan View is quite simple, I added it

Comment: Any default permission classes on the settings?

Comment: @IşıkKaplan   No, I have only this permission_classes  in view